# Kendo UI Angular grid: Will it be possible to use standard virtualization/grouping without handling the events myself?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I've started evaluating the Angular implementation of the Kendo UI grid for our company and like most of it so far. One thing however that I like better in other grids I've seen so far is that the standard ordering/virtualization/grouping behavior is handled internally by the grid so that I don't have to write code for it in my view models.

Now I think it is great that you are able to handle it yourself if you want to tweak performance or implement some specific behavior but we are using a lot of grids in different applications and pages and very often the standard behavior suffices. If we change to the Kendo UI Angular grid now we would have to implement the handling for all the features in all our view models as far a I understand your implementation so far.

So my question is if this is just how you handle it in the beta or if this is already how it is planned for the final release? If this is how you plan to do in the final release then do you have some suggestion on how to get the logic into our view models without just copy/pasting the same code into each of them?

Thanks!